# Convert coordinates to a different coordinate axis

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, 3d, coordinate-systems, matrix-equations

Sorry for any forum rules I have broken, I needed a quick answer.

I want to create a plane including 3 nonlinear points on a 3d coordinate system, one being the origin. I also need to create a transformation matrix to switch between the points on the $xyz$ system to the new system and back.

Pretty much I want to make a plane between points $(0,0,0)$, $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$, $(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)$, and then make a transformation matrix to multiply any 3d point by to get the coordinates on the new plane. I assume I can get back by multiplying by the inverse.

I can find the normal vector using cross product between two vectors between the points, but would prefer another way using matrices. I also don't want to use too many sines and cosines in the transformation matrix.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Without further assumptions about the two vectors $\vec{v}_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $\vec{v}_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, the transformation that converts the standard coordinates to the new coordinates will distort shapes.  For example, rectangles will turn into arbitrary parellelograms.

Comment: What does it mean "to get the coordinates on the new plane" for an arbitrary point in $3$-space?

Comment: Do you want to be able to translate a point in the plane $(u, v) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ into a corresponding point on the plane spanned by the vectors $\vec{v}_0, \vec{v}_1 \in \Bbb{R}^3$ (and vice versa)?

Comment: I want to be able to take a point in 3d, find a transformation vector according to the new plane, and then convert that vector back into 3d coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I am a high schooler trying to solve a problem for a competition I am participating in; I have no clue about the math terms you are using (∈ℝ2)

Comment: Sure.  $\Bbb{R}$ stands for the set of real numbers.  The notation $\Bbb{R}^2$ just means the $2$-dimensional real plane ($2$ real numbers specify each point).  The notation $(u, v) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ means that the ordered pair $(u, v)$ is an element of (is *in*) the plane.

Comment: thanks, and yes, I do want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note.*  I am assuming that you want a linear transformation that takes the vector $(1, 0)$ to $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0)$ and $(0, 1)$ to $(X_1, Y_1, Z_1)$.

Observe that any vector $(u, v)$ in the plane can be written
$$
(u, v) = u \, (1, 0) + v \, (0, 1).
$$
Therefore, the transformation (let's call it $T$) sends $(u, v)$ to
$$
u \, (X_0, Y_0, Z_0) + v \, (X_1, Y_1, Z_1) 
= ( uX_0 + vX_1, \; uY_0 + vY_1, \; uZ_0 + vZ_1),
$$
which is a vector in $3$-space.

Now if you want the transformation to have an inverse $T^{-1}$, then given a vector $(X, Y, Z)$ in the plane sitting in $3$-space, you have to be able to express each of its three coordinates in terms of parts of the two given vectors that defined the plane.  In other words, you have to be able to solve the system of linear equations:
$$
\left\{ \!
\begin{array}{rcrcl}
uX_0 &+& vX_1 &=& X \\
uY_0 &+& vY_1 &=& Y \\
uZ_0 &+& vZ_1 &=& Z
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Does this help?  I can say more if you are familiar with matrices and their inverses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So to clarify, this creates an artificial origin at (0,0) if (X0,Y0,Z0) is on the path of (1,0) and (X1,Y1,Z1) is on the path of (0,1). The plane crosses the origin. T takes a vector on the 2d plane and turns it into a 3d vector. How can I turn T into a matrix?